# javascript and CSS animation conflict - translate doesn't works, opacity does

Tags: javascript, css, animation, conflict

I have a piece of code tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/PTtJx/
simple CSS animation and some JS to display screen size.
the code line num. 7 stopt the CSS animation: translate.
removing this line and it works again.
I didn't find any reason for that.
does anyone can confirm it is a bug or a faulty code.
thanks

```
<script>
function resize(){
var P,H,W,f_Factor=1;
W=window.innerWidth;
H=window.innerHeight;

P=Math.floor(f_Factor*(8+W/50));

if(P<4){P=4;}document.body.style.fontSize=P+"px";
document.getElementById("dimensions").innerHTML = W + "x" + H;
}

resize();
</script>

<style>
.slide_1 {
z-index:50;
top: 0px;
left:0%;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;

font-size: 30px;

}

.slide_1 {
-webkit-animation: slide 3s infinite;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0%  0%;
 }

@-webkit-keyframes slide {

    0%{-webkit-transform: translate(0%);}
    50%{-webkit-transform: translate(250%) ;text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,1);}
    100%{-webkit-transform: translate(0%);}
}

</style>
<html> 
<span  class="slide_1"  id="dimensions">ABC</span> 
</html>
```

Comment: try to indent better your code

Comment: As far as I can see the animation works.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the property is null.

I surround the `document.body.style.fontSize=P+"px";` with a try/ catch like:

`try{document.body.style.fontSize=P+"px";}catch(ex)
{alert(ex.message);}`

The exception is "cannot read property 'style' of null.
The error means that the element doesn't exist..

I hope it helps ;)

Comment: ok,adding this line
<boby style="font-size:18px;">
resolved the problem,

Comment: You can test it.. set the font size to a special div using jquery. Do not set the font size to the full body.

Comment: The slide (also with 250%) works for me.. but the fontsize is always the same.
Okay ;)

Comment: well, it doesn't look like it works after all.
the only case the animation doesn't works is when I use percentage.

if I replace the translate(100%) with translate(100px) the animation works ok.
the text-shadow does works however.

btw, I don't want to use jquery.

Comment: the animation works fine for me (also with percentage) ..
which browser do you use?

Comment: I am using Chrome.
I tested it now in FF and it does works there.
I think it is a bug in chrome